# Display all terms from a specific vocabulary in my template

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a page where I want to display the terms for the vocabulary named "Services" in an unordered list. The Page is in no way associated with the vocabulary, I just want to display the terms at the end of the article. What should I type in my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't type anything in a file.

Instead, use the Views module and create a block view that lists all of the terms in that vocabulary, then display that block immediately after the main content on the specific page that you're talking about.

Comment: Of course, why didn't I think of that.